# Memory issue warning in my app, but app doesn't consume a lot memory

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-leaks

I get an lowmemory waring in my app and then it crashes.
But when I look into the memory consumption, I can't recognize any memory limits of my app. I also can't see any crashlogs on my device.

Does someone has a hint for me ?

in my didReceiveMemoryWarning I set a breakpoint.

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        print("memory low received !!!");
    }

then i checked the memory and it looks like following:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I know already what are memory leaks, so it doesn't help to give me hints in general. I am interested to know if I read the memory usage correctly and if we can see that the problem is the app or the general invironment.
I run my app several times and do always the same actions (automated by code) and from 5 times it crashes one time.

Comment: does your device have enough space for storing  images.? i

Comment: Do you mean disk space ? I see 493 MB available in the storage of the settings.

Comment: Seems like you are loading Images in the app from internet, That might be the reason If you mishandle the image assets. check in instruments if your code is generating repetitive image assets. And also handle memory warning in the didReciveMemoryWarrning delete all the unnecessary assets in this function.

Comment: I am not loading Images from the Internet. I don't know where you can read this from my informations. I can start the app several times and do the same thing, but sometimes it gets into lowmemory issue. Then I check with the XCOde Memory viewer and I can't see any special memory usages. Do I missread the screenshot, or can we simply not trust the Apples developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low memory warning can be caused for a lot of reasons. If you see that your application is not using too much memory and if does not crash due to the memory usage then there is no issue.

But generally I believe 3 things can trigger the warning:

- Your application is using too much memory (does not seem to be the case)
- You have other applications opened that consume most of your memory which will be killed by the OS on warning (probably your case)
- Your application memory consumption keeps jumping up and down which should be avoided and the OS may kill your app in this situation (I hope you are not doing something that could produce this)

Comment: Probably it could be case 3. But in case it is true how to debug or monitor this, when the standard XCODE tools are not showing the right measures (this is only assumpotion from me)

Comment: Well looking at your chart it seems quite linear but the peak seems to be at over 200MB which is quite a lot. The warning is triggered afterwards so using a breakpoint will not make your app stop where the issue is in your case. So what ARE you doing that takes up 200MB of memory?

Comment: I am drawing a Map with CALayers and CATextlayers. When moving, scaling the map manually I didn't get any problems so far. Now I am moving/scaling the map automated to create a movie. My automated move crashes around every 5 run.

Comment: But still this is not enough to crash. If you look at the piechart on the right you will see that rest of the applications are using about as much memory that you are left with about 300MB so I can assume at least one app was killed to gain enough free memory which triggered the warning.

Comment: Try to analyze what your code does when drawing. Comment out a few things and see what produces the majority of the memory. Then when you feel you have enough info about it but do not know how to optimize it I would suggest you to post another question with the code and your results included asking how could you optimize this.